# Time based workflow queue

Tags: time-dependent-workflow, time

Currently i am sending notification to owner and manager of lead after 5 days from lead creation based on few user profiles rule criteria in workflow.
Now i need to send notificatios only  when status on open so added the condition in workflow rule criteria.
Please let me know what about the notifications which are already in queue
Let me know how to test this time based workflow

Comment: Records in the time-based workflow queue are not affected unless the underlying records are modified by DML (update/delete) and such DML causes the workflow rule to remove the record from its current place in the time-based position. This is covered in the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into setup, you can find the time-based workflow rule queue located under `monitoring`. This feature lets you search for time based rules currently scheduled based on criteria like:

1. Scheduled date
2. Created date
3. Rule name
4. Object
   Etc

You can go there to find any time based workflow rules still scheduled. You may also delete them if desired.